# Joomla 1.5 Administrator URL not working

Tags: administrator, joomla-1.5

I've inherited a quite old site running Joomla 1.5. I unfortunately cannot find the  URL for the admin login. www.website.net/administrator returns a 404 error. The server is running php 7.2. Any tips on where to get started here? Thanks!

Comment: [J1.5:Get_to_know_the_Administrator_Back-end_of_Joomla!](https://docs.joomla.org/J1.5:Get_to_know_the_Administrator_Back-end_of_Joomla!) says that you are using the appropriate url.  I fear something else is impeding you.

Comment: The answer to the similar (not a duplicate) question at https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/16292/120 may help

Comment: The 404 error might be because of security extension that is installed on the website that masks the administrator url. Anyway, I don't think J 1.5 will run with php 7.2. Maybe you should try to set the php version to 5.2 first to make your work easier.

Comment: Login to the cPanel/plesk whatever and verify that there is really a directory called administrator. I recall back in the times when dinosaurs roamed the earth and 1.5 was current there were tutorials explaining how to rename the /administrator directory in an attempt to hide it.

Comment: Thanks. I got it sorted. Turns out there were old Joomla files sitting on the server. Maybe an old site. The site is actually and old php site.